# Best way to split a table in Parent-Child to avoid duplicated information in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the easiest way to split a location table in mysql?

Current table has:
country_code, Country_name, state_code, state_name, city_code, city_name

I would like to split it in three tables

country table  (Parent) : country_code, Country_name

state table  (child-parent): country_code, state_code, state_name

city table (child): state_code, city_code, city_name

Is it possible to do it with a simple query after creating each table and their foreign key separately?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is as normalized as you're going to get. Use a foreign key on the city table to state_code, and the same from the state table to the country table on country_code.

When you query the table, us an inner join between the tables as needed to get the data from state and country.

To populate from the existing table, loop through the table and insert the unique countries into the new country table, then the unique states, and finally a 3rd query for the cities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to run 3 queries. First create the tables, then do something along these lines 3 times. Just make sure to run the "SELECT" only to see the data you are adding.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (country_code, Country_name)
SELECT country_code, Country_name
FROM old_table
GROUP BY country_code;
```